# No return from HTML using AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get the data using AJAX. My code is below. Basically what I am trying to do is: The first element contains `HTML` and the second element contains another `JSON` array with the data inside.
The 2nd element work find, but 1st element did not return any results.
If I write the code like this

```
$html = $cont[0][0];
```

It returns the results when I write code like this

```
$html = '<div>This is Html</div>';
```

Now I really did not know why this happen. If I `echo` the 1st one `code` style it show the data but did not pass it.

**script Code**

```
<script>
function get_data_from_rul() { //alert('ting');
    var post_url = jQuery('#prod_url').val();
     //alert('hmm');    
    jQuery.ajax({
      url: 'ajax.php',
      type: 'post',
      data: {'post_url': post_url},
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(serverResponse) {
          //location.reload();
          //console.log(data);
          jQuery('#prod_detail').val(serverResponse.html);
          var data = JSON.parse(serverResponse.data);


          jQuery('#meta_description').val(data.description);
          jQuery('#meta_keyword').val(data.keywords);
          jQuery('#prod_title').val(data.page_title);

      }


    });
}
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<input type="text" id="prod_url" name="prod_url"  class="large" onkeyup="get_data_from_rul();" />
<br />
<textarea id="meta_description" rows="8" cols="90"></textarea><br />
<textarea id="meta_keyword" rows="8" cols="90"></textarea><br />
<textarea id="prod_title" rows="8" cols="90"></textarea><br />
<textarea id="prod_detail" rows="8" cols="90"></textarea>
```

**ajax.php Code:**

```
<?php

    $url = $_REQUEST['post_url'];

function get_web_page( $url )
{
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,     // return web page
        CURLOPT_HEADER         => false,    // don't return headers
        CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,     // follow redirects
        CURLOPT_ENCODING       => "",       // handle all encodings
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT      => "spider", // who am i
        CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER    => true,     // set referer on redirect
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,      // timeout on connect
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT        => 120,      // timeout on response
        CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS      => 10,       // stop after 10 redirects
    );

    $ch      = curl_init( $url );
    curl_setopt_array( $ch, $options );
    $content = curl_exec( $ch );
    $err     = curl_errno( $ch );
    $errmsg  = curl_error( $ch );
    $header  = curl_getinfo( $ch );
    curl_close( $ch );

    $header['errno']   = $err;
    $header['errmsg']  = $errmsg;
    $header['content'] = $content;
    return $header;
}

$result = get_web_page( $url );

preg_match('/<title>(.+)<\/title>/',$result['content'],$matches[]);
preg_match('/<div id="specs-list">([^`]*?)<\/div>/',$result['content'],$cont[]);

$tags = get_meta_tags($url);

$keywords       = $tags['keywords'];
$description    = $tags['description'];
$page_title     = $matches[0][1];

$html = $cont[0][0];
$data = json_encode(array('keywords'=>$keywords,'description'=>$description,'page_title'=>$page_title));
$response = array('html'=>$html, 'data'=>$data);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: Why would you add brackets to the last argument in preg_match, remove `[]` from the end.

Comment: i did it but it not work. and i don't think that this have any effect. But any how i try it but still no results. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why you have called twice `json_encode` in `$data` and in `$response`? You should only on `$response` to call `json_encode`.

Are you sure that you should be on first of array `$cont[0][0]` maybe not in `$cont[0]` instead?

```
preg_match('/<div id="specs-list">([^`]*?)<\/div>/',$result['content'],$cont); // Remove this [] braces, it is not neccessary, on code after you should check array
```

Part:

```
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);

$keywords       = $tags['keywords'];
$description    = $tags['description'];
$page_title     = $matches[0][1];

if (isset($cont[0][0])
{
   $html = $cont[0][0];
   // echo($cont[0][0]); // Uncomment to check if you really have results.
}

// If you are not sure of returned result check with print_r and find array
// var_dump(isset($cont[0][1])); ....

$data = (array('keywords'=>$keywords,'description'=>$description,'page_title'=>$page_title));
$response = array('html'=>$html, 'data'=>$data);
echo json_encode($response);
```

Not sure, but hope this helps.

Comment: NO having same problem. there is value in $html but as i elaborate above, how it work.

Comment: What you got when make `var_dump($cont);` ?